# Why I get Attribute value must be constant error?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to add current date to url String in HTTP @GET, but I'm getting `Attribute value must be constant` error. I can't figure why? I'm using retrofit 2.

```
public interface API {

  final Date c = new Date();
  final String date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c);

  static final String url = ("/modules/json/json/Index?costNumber=0417&firstDay="+date+"&language=fi");


  @GET(url)
  Call<Menu> getMenuName();
```

Comment: java's basics: because of `+date+` plus fact that `data` is not constant ... which makes `url` not constant

Comment: @Selvin yea I know but then how I can get the date to url? For example if date is 2017-01-18 then url would be /modules/json/json/Index?costNumber=0417&firstDay=2017-01-18&language=fi

Comment: Make it parameter of getMenuName, read the documentation how to do it

Comment: url is static while date is not.

Comment: *url is static while date is not.* @JimmyB it doesn't matter as it's a field of interface ... so they are both static ... infact you dont need nor `static` nor `final` http://ideone.com/hxRLtE as interface fields are implicitly static and final

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, I failed to notice that it's an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Selvin already pointed out in the comments it's because of `date` not being a constant.

Using retrofit you usually make this a query parameter, so you can change `getMenuName` to:

```
@GET("/modules/json/json/Index")
Call<Menu> getMenuName(
       @Query("costNumber") String costNumber,
       @Query("firstDay") String firstDay,
       @Query("language") String language);
```

You can then call the method with the proper parameters:

```
getMenuName("0417", date, "fi");
```

Retrofit will know how to build the url for you. Notice that this makes it also much easier to make the same call with different `costNumber` and `firstDay`, than having a hardcoded url.

Answer (score 2):

Fred's answer is the correct solution for your case. However, for the sake of complete information, Retrofit 2 does support dynamic URLs. You can pass it as a `@Url` parameter to your interface method, for example:

```
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> getMenuName(@Url String url);
```

You don't need to specify the URL in the `@GET` annotation. Retrofit will take the value from the passed `url`. This gives you the option to request data from dynamic URLs, which can be useful in some cases.

You can find more info here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests