# Why I get Attribute value must be constant error in Retrofit Post Operation?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to add **token** to url String in **HTTP @POST**, but I'm getting

> **Attribute value must be constant error**

. I can't figure why? I'm using retrofit 2.

**

```
public interface API { 

  static final String url = ("/secure/frrest/oauth2/token/"+ Prefs.getSmartPassAccessToken(App.getContext()) + "?_action=revokeTokens");


  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST(url)
    void smartpassnonpersistentlogout(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
            @Field("client_id") String client_id,
            Callback<SmartPassResponse> callback);
```

**

Comment: Please do some search before asking a question. This one has been already answered, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720327/why-i-get-attribute-value-must-be-constant-error or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157370/java-code-wont-compile-due-to-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-error/39157786

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead

```
public interface API { 
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/secure/frrest/oauth2/token/{token}")
void smartpassnonpersistentlogout(@Path("token") String token,@Query("_action")String _action,@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
            @Field("client_id") String client_id,
            Callback<SmartPassResponse> callback);
```

Then it can be called like this

```
String token=Prefs.getSmartPassAccessToken(pass_context);
yourinterface.smartpassnonpersistentlogout(token,"revokeTokens",...add remaining params);
```